# What calls PostgreSQL's initdb on package installation?

Tags: server, packaging, postgresql

I'm trying to a build a custom package of PostgreSQL with some configuration tweaks suitable for our application. Part of that configuration involves a pg_hba.conf using "trust" instead of the defaults.

I can see when I install a setup script is triggered and the PostgreSQL 'initdb' command is run. This copies the sample config files and applies some transformations to it (keyword replacement) and copies into /etc. However even if I remove the keywords from the pg_hba.conf.sample file and hard code the values I want they automagically get reverted to the defaults.

I've tried to follow the post install scripts but all I can see is a call to configure_version which isn't anywhere in the PostgreSQL source code.

So what is the call-chain from post installation scripts to the initdb program being called? And how can I tweak the parameters of the initdb call for my preferred form of authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `postgresql-8.4.postinst`, the line immediately above the call to `configure_version` is:

```
. /usr/share/postgresql-common/maintscripts-functions
```

That will load all the functions from that file, which includes `configure_version`. That file is found in the **postgresql-common** package.

Comment: So why can't I find maintscripts-functions or a file (other than the postinst script) containing configure_versions in the package source tree?

Comment: ahh, I was under the impression everything was built from the one package. As you say postgresql-common is a separate package.

Comment: Right, the Depends: for the installed package may use tools from those packages (in this case, postgresql-common).